# some images work but not all of them in XAMPP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, xampp

so im currenrly coding a image viewer for my website but where my problem lies is all my websites images are in my `img` folder and all of the older ones work but if i add any more they wont show on my site? all of my folders are in the `htdocs` and everything else works just not SOME of the images.... heres the html code :)

```
`    <!--image viewer-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
<div class="big_img_wrapper">
                <img src="img/maxresdefault.jpg" id="big_img_1" class="big_img">
                <img src="img/sunset.png" id="big_img_2" class="big_img">
                <img src="img/background1.png" id="big_img_3" class="big_img">

            </div>
            <div class="thumbs_img_wrapper">
                <img src="img/maxresdefault.jpg" id="thumbs_img_1" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="img/sunset.png" id="thumbs_img_2" calss="thumbs_img">
                <img src="img/background1.png" id="thumbs_img_3" calss="thumbs_img">
            </div>
</div>`
```

The spesific image that isnt working here is "maxresdefault.jpg"? this is happening throught my site with any more photos that i add... any ideas??

Comment: not sure but calss spell is wrong its should be class="thumbs_img" insted of calss="thumbs_img"

Comment: i got the  basic code from somwhere else but its only the very 1st photo that wont work in this case.... so it couldnt be that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I can see from the above information is, it just not working for the only **jpg** image. Perhaps you should verify the image in your image folder has the same **jpg** extension. It might be **png**.

Comment: Change the image that is not working and try another one.

Comment: Got it now!! Thankyou, it took a few different things but i backally SAVED the image from google as apposed to draging to the folder AND double checking all images names etc..